How to include C libraries in cibuildwheel Github Action for Cython module?
I'm trying to separate a few libraries from my Python project, into a C++ submodule, that should improve the performance, using Cython. Now, I've managed to make the module an compile it, but now I want to make possible for it to be used in more platforms, not just my computer, and that's when I found that Github provides a way to do this through GHA, moreso, I found that there is cibuildwheel which helps to manage all this work, but I haven't been able to make it work. Seems like the problem might come from the fact that my CPP module requires 2 non-native libraries(libass, and libjsoncpp), and apparently the platforms GH use for the build are not exactly equal, hence I haven't been able to discover how to include them in the build.
setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os
import sys

# Determine platform-specific library paths
if sys.platform == "win32":
    # Windows
    vcpkg_root = os.getenv('VCPKG_ROOT', 'C:\\vcpkg')  # Set your vcpkg path
    libass_head = os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'include')
    libass_lib = os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'packages', 'libass_x64-windows', 'lib', 'ass.lib')
    json_lib = os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'lib', 'jsoncpp.lib')
    json_head = os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'include')
else:
    # Linux
    libass_lib = "/usr/lib"
    libass_head = "/usr/include/ass"
    json_lib = "/usr/local/lib"
    json_head = "/usr/include/"

ext_module = Extension(
    "test_module",
    sources=["test_module.pyx", "testmodule.cpp"],
    language="c++",
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
    libraries=["ass", "jsoncpp"],  
    library_dirs=[libass_lib, json_lib],  
    include_dirs=[libass_head, json_head],
)

setup(
    name="test_module",
    version='0.1.0',
    ext_modules=cythonize([ext_module]),
)

testmodule.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>
#include <ass/ass.h>
#include <json/json.h>
using namespace std;

// Rest of the file

build_wheel.yml
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build wheel for ${{ matrix.python }}-${{ matrix.buildplat[1] }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.buildplat[0] }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        buildplat:
        - [ubuntu-20.04, manylinux_x86_64]
        #- [ubuntu-20.04, manylinux_i686]
        #- [windows-2019, win_amd64]
        - [windows-2019, win32]
        python: ["cp39", "cp310"]
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies (Windows)
        if: contains(matrix.buildplat[0], 'windows')
        run: |
          # Alternative Windows method using vcpkg
          git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git C:\vcpkg
          C:\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
          C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install libass
          C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install jsoncpp

      - name: Install dependencies (Linux)
        if: contains(matrix.buildplat[0], 'ubuntu')
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y libass-dev libjsoncpp-dev

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt  # Install dependencies from requirements.txt

      - name: Show DEBUG Linux
        if: contains(matrix.buildplat[0], 'ubuntu')
        run: |
          whereis libass
          whereis libjsoncpp
          whereis ass
          whereis jsoncpp
          ls /usr/include/ass
          ls /usr/include

      - name: Show DEBUG Windows
        if: contains(matrix.buildplat[0], 'windows')
        run: |
          ls C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include
          ls C:\vcpkg\packages
          ls C:\vcpkg\packages\libass_x64-windows
          ls C:\vcpkg\packages\libass_x64-windows\lib
          ls C:\vcpkg\packages\libass_x64-windows\include

      - name: Build wheels
        uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.8.1
        with:
          output-dir: wheelhouse
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: ${{ matrix.python }}-${{ matrix.buildplat[1] }}
          CIBW_SKIP: "cp34-* cp35-*"
          CIBW_BEFORE_BUILD: |
            pip install setuptools==59.6.0 wheel Cython
          CIBW_ENVIRONMENT_WINDOWS: >
            INCLUDE="C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"
            LIB="C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
            CXXFLAGS="-IC:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include"
            LDFLAGS="-LC:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
          CIBW_ENVIRONMENT_LINUX: >
            CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
            LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"

      - name: Show generated wheels
        run: ls wheelhouse

      - name: Upload wheels
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: built-wheels
          path: ./wheelhouse/*.whl

Sorry if the setup.py and yml looks very messy, but I've been trying many things to understand what's happening inside of the instance doing the build.
In the case of my Linux builds, it's throwing this error, which seems to imply is not finding either the headers and/or the code of the libraries.
testmodule.cpp:6:10: fatal error: ass/ass.h: No such file or directory
6 | #include <ass/ass.h>

And in the case of the Windows builds, seems like I've managed to make them point to the right headers, but it's throwing LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'ass.lib', which I understand means the lib files are not the right ones(?) I've tried to use the ones at installed and packages in vcpkg, but neither are working.
Does someone knows what might be wrong either on my setup.py or build_wheels.yml?

Ok, I think I finally found what my problem was, so let me detail it a little:
First note that I was installing the libraries outside the cibuildwheel, this is apparently not right, hence I had to add a few lines like these into the cibuildwheel step:
      CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_WINDOWS: >
        C:\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat &&
        C:\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install &&
        C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install libass &&
        C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install jsoncpp
      CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_LINUX: >
        yum update &&
        yum install -y libass-devel jsoncpp-devel

Second, for the Windows build, note that I'm running on a win32 build, which means 32 bits version, Window's VCPKG is a little shitty at controlling which version of a library is installing, and because it was adding files in the x64 folder, I though I was running on a 64-bits version, that's why when importing the bins into the project, it didn't work, they were no the right ones for the version, so I changed my Windows version to win_amd64 and it worked, furthermore, adding a few extra lines to control which versión of the libs are getting installed would make this more of a correct answer.
TL;DR
YAML
- name: Build wheels
        uses: pypa/cibuildwheel@v2.20.0
        with:
          output-dir: wheelhouse
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: ${{ matrix.python }}-${{ matrix.buildplat[1] }}
          CIBW_SKIP: "cp34-* cp35-*"
          CIBW_BEFORE_BUILD: >
            pip install setuptools==59.6.0 wheel Cython
          CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_WINDOWS: >
            C:\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat &&
            C:\vcpkg\vcpkg integrate install &&
            C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install libass &&
            C:\vcpkg\vcpkg install jsoncpp
          CIBW_BEFORE_ALL_LINUX: >
            yum update &&
            yum install -y libass-devel jsoncpp-devel

setup.py
if sys.platform == "win32":
    # Windows
    # Check if 32-bits or 64-bits | TODO
    vcpkg_root = os.getenv('VCPKG_ROOT', 'C:\\vcpkg')  # Set your vcpkg path
    libs = [
        os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'lib'),
        os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'bin'),
    ]
    includes = [
        os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'include'),
        os.path.join(vcpkg_root, 'installed', 'x64-windows', 'include')
    ]
else:
    # Linux
    libs = [
        "/usr/lib",
    ]
    includes = [
        "/usr/include/ass",
        "/usr/include/jsoncpp",
    ]


I only have a relatively shallow understanding of cibuildwheel, but I think I might have a few useful comments to share:

cibuildwheel builds your package in a container, isolated from the CI machine, so installing the dependencies on the CI machine doesn't accomplish anything on it's own.

It looks like you give cibuildwheel paths to the include and lib directories on Windows, but not Linux, via environment variables. That might why Linux can't find the header files.

On Linux, it might be more robust to use pkgbuild to get paths to the include and lib directories, instead of hard-coding them.



No, didn't work, tried to add similar lines in my YAML to include the libraries like in Windows, but it still has the same error.

Too bad, sorry I couldn't help.
